# Making the clickable area of in-line links bigger without affecting the layout

Tags: html, css, accessibility

I'm looking to make the clickable area of links bigger than they actually are for accessibility since for the intended users it can be difficult to hit them. About 1.5x the size may be appropriate. These are links in normal text, so I cannot actually make them bigger which would mess up the layout.

I make use of HTML5, CSS3, JS or even Mozilla specific features to accomplish this as the latest Firefox version is the only target, though basic CSS/HTML rather than such hacks would of course be much preferable!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

One option that might work is to use the `:after` pseudo-element. Something like this:

```
a {
    position: relative
}
.bigger:after{
    content:"";
    padding: 50px;  
    position: absolute;
    left: -25px;
    top: -25px;
}
```

Numbers could be tweaked as you like. Only downside I can see right away is if you need to support anything pre-IE8. http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gencontent

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WD8Yh/1/).

Comment: I'm lucky in that I don't have to support any legacy browsers and this works. It got a bit wonky on actual pages (the bigger click zone not at all centred on the text) but this could be fixed using equally wonky tweaks.

Comment: Opera did'nt align the clickbox the right way for me using the above example. Something that worked better for me is the following: http://jsfiddle.net/WD8Yh/47/

Answer (score 9):

You can do it using a bigger padding.

For example:

```
.a{
    padding: 20px;
    margin: -20px; //lets keep the layout
}
```

Here you have a living example:
http://jsfiddle.net/u5kuJ/1/

**Updated:**

With your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XXgqu/1/

Comment: That doesn't work. These are links in text, the clickable area must overlap the normal text. http://jsfiddle.net/XXgqu/

Comment: That oddly makes it only clickable from the left and top. To the right of it and below it is not. Otherwise that's the effect I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I have made an update to gotohales answer, it will work with whatever the length of the text is, then add some padding.

http://jsfiddle.net/vG7UY/2/

```
a {
  position: relative;
}
  .biggerForMobile:before{
  content:""; 
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  position:absolute;
  padding:12px;
  top:-10px;
  left:-10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `:after` pseudo-element to pad the element, and using `transform` and `position` you can position the padding centered on the center of the element without impacting other elements.

Change the `padding: 30px` to whatever padding you need.

```
.padded-click {
  position: relative; 
}
.padded-click:after{
  padding: 30px;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Note: This is based on gotohales solution, which is a great approach, however using top and left with pixels values as gotohales solution does requires taking into account the width/height of the element we're padding otherwise the padding will be off center.

Answer (score -1):

I am pretty sure you cannot do what you are asking. The only things that are coming to mind are adding padding, margin and line-height. While it isn't my favorite solution, but depending on the context of the site, maybe having a page with all the links listed, which has a bigger target.

Also, maybe use the `outline` & the `outline-offset` CSS properties with good contrast to let people know are on the link.

Another thing is, people who need a bigger target, use the keyboard more often to navigate a website, so making your site more keyboard friendly may help. For example, do you have a header and a sidebar, via code, does those come before the main content? If so placing a [skip nav](http://webaim.org/techniques/skipnav/) link, or a few (depending on layout), may also help.

Comment: Good advice, but the interface isn't a mouse and keyboard but a single click only touchscreen for public use, so I really do need the bigger hit zone.