# anchor padding clickable only when opacity <1

Tags: css, layout

Using trick from here: [Making the clickable area of in-line links bigger without affecting the layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15611905/making-the-clickable-area-of-in-line-links-bigger-without-affecting-the-layout), I set positive padding and negative margin on an anchor element, with the goal of extending the clickable region into some text beyond the element.

It works, but only if opacity is some value below 1!  Firefox and Chrome exhibit the same behavior.

Compact demo: http://jsfiddle.net/zGsZK/8/

CSS:

```
  a { margin-right:-250px; padding-right:250px }
 .nowork { opacity:1 }
 .works { opacity:0.999999 }
```

HTML:

```
<body>
<a href=# class=nowork>?</a> this black text is not clickable :(
<p>
<a href=# class=works>!</a> this black text is clickable, as it should be
</body>
```

Is this how it's supposed to work?  Why?   Is there a way to make it work when opacity==1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm really not sure why this works, but if you add `position:relative;` to the `nowork` class, the clickable area will appear above the text similar to the `works` class.  I believe this has something to do with how browsers render CSS, and since the `<p>` tag is rendered after the anchor, its native CSS (where `cursor:normal;` rather than `cursor:pointer;`) takes priority.

Comment: Thank you!  I only included `<p>` to separate the examples, it wasn't in my original problem and the bug (it has to be a bug, right?) survives removal of the paragraph break.  Regardless I'm happy to have a less-hacky solution.

Comment: Reddit provided this link to an explanation of why it's not a bug, which I'll include here for posterity: http://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/